# Remove multiple Conditions joined by OR from IF-statement

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, java-stream, predicate

I want to remove multiple conditions from the `if` statement.

How can I achieve that?

I think `switch` is not what I'm looking for. I'm thinking of something that respect the Open close principal or using an interface to call the different `boolean` method.

Now I'm using :

```
 if (utilisateur.isAdmin() || utilisateur.isWebMaster() || utilisateur.isAdministrateurLiferay() || utilisateur.estResponsableCommercial()) {
```

Example of a method :

```
public boolean estResponsableCommercial() {
    return roles.stream().anyMatch(Role::isResponsableCommercial);
}
```

Comment: `if (!utilisateur.isRegularUser()) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for a way to combine *predicates* in order to use them in operations like `anyMatch`.

If so, you can achieve this using static method [`Predicate.or()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#or(java.util.function.Predicate)):

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> Predicate<T> combineWithOr(Predicate<T>... predicates) {
    
    return Arrays.stream(predicates).reduce(t -> true, Predicate::or); // if `predicates` is empty then method would return `true`, another way of expressing this: `reduce(Predicate::or).orElse(t -> true)`
}
```

And that how you can apply it to obtain a composite predicate:

```
Predicate<UserRole> combinedPredicate = combineWithOr(
    UserRole::isAdmin,
    UserRole::isWebMaster,
    UserRole::isAdministrateurLiferay,
    UserRole::estResponsableCommercial
);
```

```
public static boolean hasMatchingRole(Collection<UserRole> roles,
                                      Predicate<UserRole> predicate){
    
    return roles.stream().anyMatch(predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with an Enum:

```
public enum Role {
   public abstract boolean check(User user);
   ADMIN {
      public boolean check(User user) {
         return user.isAdmin();
      }
   },
   WEBMASTER {
      public boolean check(User user) {
         return user.isWebMaster();
      }
   };
   
   public boolean checkRoles(User user) {
       for(Role role : Role.values()) {
           if(role.check(user)) {
               return true;
           }
       }
       return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static boolean isEstResponsableCommercial(List<String> roles, String roleYouLookingFor) {
    return roles.stream().anyMatch(r->r.equals(roleYouLookingFor));
    }
```

Signature of anyMatch is:
boolean anyMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate)